# How come I cannot import my protocol in a class in my iOS project?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created a protocol file "Protocol.h" and tried to import it into a view controller header .h file with

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Protocol.h"
```

However, XCode notes that the file "Protocol.h" cannot be found. Why not? Is is definitely in the same folder as the view controller header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case-sensitive -- is your file Protocol.h with the correct capitalization?

Comment: Thanks, yes, the case matches.

Comment: It's just a simple file open -- are you sure they are in the same folder (not just the same Xcode Group).  Just recheck carefully.  If it's still a problem, try restarting Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, using `#import "myproject/Protocol.h"` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in your view controller header files, before the @interface line, you should use:

```
@class Protocol;
```

instead of:

```
#import "Protocol.h"
```

Try that and see if it works. If it does not, do you have some kind of circular header reference going on? There are lots of hints and suggestions about what to do in that case, search for "objective-c circular header" on Google for more information.

EDIT: And you can always try to move the #import line into your .m file instead of in your .h file. It is quick and dirty and a sure way to avoid circular header references.